# Dynamic CRUD against unknown/multiple MSSQL databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, node.js

I would like to get some ideas about how retrieve data from a MSSQL database with the constraints for all the columns. I'm listing all the databases on a server, and let the user choose the database, and after that, let them choose a table to CRUD against. This is going to be shown in a javascript grid ([Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)) for inline editing. 
It's going to be very close to what you get when you rightclick a table in MSSQL Management Studio and select *Edit top 200*

**Chalenges**:

1. The application should access a bunch of different databases that often change, so generating POCOs is out of the question. The databases are also very often porly made and does not contain FKs as they should.
2. I do need to have some server side validation, and preferably client side as well for all the columns, so I do need to get the information about datatype, nvarchar length, nullable or not and so on from the DB.

I'm used to program in **C#** with **EF**/**ADO.NET**, but i would not mind trying some other languages like [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/), if there are any good support for what I'm after (Not interested in PHP though).

I was thinking about using ASP.NET MVC with ADO.NET and read the data into some models like this:

```
public class GridVM 
{
    public IEnumerable<Column> ColumnDefinitions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Column 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } //perhaps public Type Type?
    public bool Nullable { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
}
```

And then creating a list of dynamics with the number of properties corresponding with the number of entries in the **ColumnDefinitions**.

```
dynamic 
{
    public object column1 { get; set; }
    public object column2 { get; set; }
    public object column3 { get; set; }
    //etc, so that I get properties for all the columns
}
```

I do have some code for binding retrieved data from a [DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) to a data model, ignoring the property names not corresponding with the column names, but I need to do it without having a known data model.

**The questions**:

Is this a good approach or should i reconsider using some other technique or method? Are there any pitfalls with this approach that I'm not seeing right now?

Comment: Honestly this is a nightmare. Why do your databases change all the time? How can you now know which database? Are all the tables so denormalized that you can get away with directly editing the table? To me the question is not how to write this application but how do you fix the database so it isn't such a complete disaster.

Comment: hehe.. this is my life for now and unfortunately there are a lot of users in those systems, so we have to add new functionality sometimes.. but yea, most of the databases are a disaster, but I'm building a new system to replace them, but that will take some time. Although, I would like to build a tool like this for all the rookies so they don't make things even worse than they already are ^_0